# Why does one of my values change?

Tags: c#

So I have this;

```
var emailA = ConstructEmailA();
SnedEmailA(emailA.Append("</body>").ToString());

var emailB = ConstructEmailB(emailA);
SendEmailB(emailB.ToString());
```

Which works fine. Essentially, ConstructEmailB takes emailA and adds to it. However, I originally had this:

```
var emailA = ConstructEmailA();
var emailB = ConstructEmailB(emailA);
SnedEmailA(emailA.Append("</body>").ToString());                
SendEmailB(emailB.ToString());
```

Which did not work as expected. Instead of emailA and emailB being different, emailA contained the same info as emailB. How come?

Here is my ConstructEmailB method:

```
private StringBuilder ConstructEmailB(StringBuilder email)
{
    email.Append("Append stuff");

    return email;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which did not work as expected. Instead of emailA and emailB being different, emailA contained the same info as emailB. How come?

Because `emailA` *is* `emailB`.  They are both references to the same `StringBuilder` object, the only difference being *when* you call `SendEmail`.  In the first case you

1. construct `emailA`.
2. Append to `emailA`.
3. Capture the value *at that point in time* and send it to `SendEmailA`.
4. "Construct `emailB`, which is really just appending to `emailA` and then send that.

In case 2 you have:

1. Construct `emailA` and `emailB`.  They are identical because they are both references to the same `StringBuilder`.
2. Append `'` to emailA (and thus, also to `emailB`) and send it.
3. Send `emailB`.

Answer (score 2):

(Going through the second scenario, the one you don't understand.)

You're only creating a single `StringBuilder` object. You're passing a reference to that object into `ConstructEmailB`, which is modifying the contents of that object, and returning the same reference back again.

So you end up with *one* `StringBuilder` after the call to `ConstructEmailB`, with "Append stuff" at the end. You're then appending to that `StringBuilder`, and calling `ToString()` on it twice. That will give the same result twice.

I suspect these two articles I wrote a while ago may help you understand:

- [Reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [Parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)

I'd like to emphasize that it's *absolutely critical* that you understand what's going on here. While there are various ways of working round it, don't change your code at all (other than for experimentation) until you're *sure* you understand what's going on.